# Diagnosing 403 forbidden error from wget command

Tags: cmd, wget, http-status-code-403

When I try the following code, I get a 403 forbidden error, and I can't work out why.

```
wget --random-wait --wait 1 --no-directories --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36" --no-parent --span-hosts --accept jpeg,jpg,bmp,gif,png --secure-protocol=auto referer=https://pixabay.com/images/search/ --recursive --level=2 -e robots=off --load-cookies cookies.txt --input-file=pixabay_background_urls.txt
```

It returns:

```
--2021-09-01 18:12:06--  https://pixabay.com/photos/search/wallpaper/?cat=backgrounds&pagi=2
Connecting to pixabay.com (pixabay.com)|104.18.20.183|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2021-09-01 18:12:06 ERROR 403: Forbidden.
```

Notes:

-The input file has the the url 'https://pixabay.com/photos/search/wallpaper/?cat=backgrounds&pagi=2 ' page3, page 4 etc separated by new lines

-I used the long form for the flags just so I could remember what they were.

-I used a cookie file generated from the website called 'cookies.txt' and made sure it was up to date.

-I used the referer 'https://pixabay.com/images/search/' that I found by looking at the headers in Google DevTools.

-I'm able to visit these URLs normally without any visible captcha requirements

-I noticed one of the cookies _cf_bm had a Secure = TRUE- so needed to be sent using https. I'm not sure whether I'm doing that or not

It might not actually be possible to do, perhaps cloudflare is a deciding factor. But I'd like to know if it was something that could be circumvented and whether or not it's doable to download a large number of files from this website

Any solutions, insights or any other way of downloaded large numbers of image files would be very appreciated.I know pixabay has an API which I might use as a last resort, but I think it's very rate limited.

Answer (score 0):

It seems these images download sites detect that a server is querying them, rather than a real person on a normal browser. It would probably appear as futile to try to circumvent this as to try and fool Google with SEO tricks, as they will likely be in an ongoing battle trying to stop people doing mass downloads.

I quit from a company that was trying to do that to manipulate images from Google images to pass off as their own.

The 403 is usually reserved for failed logins, but is applicable if being used to reject non-standard access to resources.

I think that these image download sites should return a 200 response for HEAD ONLY https requests so that links to their images can be checked for validity. This would protect their resources while allowing proper automated site maintenance checks that include checking external links.

Answer (score 0):

First, you would need to inspect your
[Tired.com](http://tired.com/) Then you would inspect the element on that website. Go to Network, and reload the website while your developer pane is open in the Network tab

[image: screenshot of how the developer pane in network looks like]

Once the reload is completed click on the domain name (in this case tired.com), and click on Headers

[image: Header part of the network]

"User-Agent:" In my case I see

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/118.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

Copy the User-Agent value and then go to your terminal and enter

```
wget -U 'User-agent value here' -e robots=off -r -np --page-requisites --convert-links 'website url'.
```